# How do you actually use the word 'integral'?

Tags: calculus, integration, terminology

Recently I've noticed that I use the word "integral" to refer to two distinct concepts. I want to express myself more clearly, so my question is:

> **Question.** Given a function $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, are either of the following uses of the word 'integral' more standard and/or correct than the other? If so, what word or phrase should be used to refer to the other notion?
>
> - Speaking of *the* integral of $f$, meaning the number $\int_a^b f(x) dx.$
> - Speaking of *an* integral of $f$, meaning an $F:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $F'=f$.

Comment: The first is an integral, the second a *primitive*.

Comment: Definite vs indefinite integral.

Comment: Such an $F$ can be called an *antiderivative* of $f$.

Comment: Personally I call the first one an integral and the second an antiderivative.

Comment: For what it's worth, in older literature "integral series" is what we now call "power series".

Comment: Idk, but I think of the second as an integrand.

Comment: @JacobClaassen the integrand is what inside an integral, here $f$.

Comment: I know, but for me it's easier to remember it like that.

Comment: To clarify the difference between indefinite integral and primitive: a function of the form $x\mapsto \int_a^x f$ for some fixed $a$ is an indefinite integral. Such function is a primitive under additional condition. On other hand, if $F' = f$, then under additional condition, we have $F(x) - F(a) = \int_a^x f$. So both concepts overlaps, but are technically distinct.

Comment: @JacobClaassen what is the merit to remember something which isn't correct?

Comment: Personally, I don't think it's worth being too lazy to omit the adjectives "definite" or "indefinite".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Riemann integration of functions $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, there are three concepts about "integral" under the three names "definite integral", "indefinite integral", and "primitive". (For illustration ease I use "indefinite integral" in an old-fashion way.)

The limit of the Riemann sum as the sequence of partitions "shrinks" defines the concept of definite integral. The limit of any function is unique; this justifies the "the" before "integral" in your first statement.

Given two functions, the first is called a primitive of the second if the derivative of the first is the second. The existence of a primitive of a continuous function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ turns out to be easily justified; a handy example is any function $F_{c}: x \mapsto \int_{c}^{x}f$ on $[a,b]$ where $c \in [a,b]$. Let us call any $F_{c}$ an indefinite integral of $f$; there being an "an" before "indefinite integral" is due to that $c$ is not unique. This existence result is called the fundamental theorem of calculus. Since $F_{c}$ is a primitive of $f$ for every $c \in [a,b]$, it follows that any constant shift $F_{c} + K$ is also a primitive of $f$. From here you can see the so-called second fundamental theorem of calculus.

As for the second statement, the author must use "an integral" to refer to "a primitive", regarding the requirement that $F'=f$.

Answer (score 2):

This is the distinction between definite and indefinite integral.

When someone says integral, they can mean both definite and indefinite integral. It can also be the solution of a differential equation, so just like in many cases, it is the context which should give away what meaning has to be given to the word integral.

Comment: "... it is the context which should give away what meaning has to be given to the word integral." Exactly that.

Comment: The word "primitive" is used in (Western) Europe rather than "indefinite integral", or "anti derivative" which is common in the America's....We learned how to "primivitize" (did I just invent a new verb in English?) and that meant to find an anti derivative

Comment: @imranfat There is a difference that a primitive is a function and an indefinite integral is used to refer to the class of all primitives. In this sense, it is possible that $\int f(x)\,dx=1+\int f(x)\,dx$.